# Laravel 5.2 cannot generate bootstrap folder

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I clone my laravel5.2 project from bitbucket into my new machine, but when I run `composer install`, or event `composer update`, there is not `bootstrap` folder has been generated it causes the error:

```
require(/home/my/personal-project/einsamer-sharing/einsamer-sharing-source/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/my/personal-project/einsamer-sharing/einsamer-sharing-source/artisan on line 16
```

I try to create new project and it just works normally.

What wrong I did?

Comment: **bootstrap** folder might be in your `.ignore` file

Comment: it should be, I think, it depends on each machine you run the project. I wonder how could I generate it. As you see, the first time we create a new project from the composer, there is no bootstrap folder.

Comment: i think there is bootstrap folder. check this: https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: Laravel bootstrap is not related to the machine. You should include it in your version control.